# Is there a way to acquire twitch video data?

Tags: web-scraping, video-streaming, data-mining, twitch

I am making a website to help video games streamers (on twitch), but to do so I need to analyze there streams and videos. I can always ask the users to download their videos from twitch and upload them on my website but I need a more automatic way... So my question is: is there a way to acquire the video data and the live stream data? Maybe by asking the user to link his twitch account? Or by using a **scraper** on the twitch website?
Note: I need the stream and videos data itself (i am going to do some image processing on them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this multiple ways.

Way 1.
Use the twitch api V5

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.get("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/<channel ID>/videos

", headers={"Client-ID":"CLIENTID"})
j = json.loads(r.text)

j['url']
```

to gather all videos and download then execute a command via python or whatever language you choose. To execute either of two options. [Youtube-DL](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl) which the command would be as follows

```
youtube-dl twitchVideoURL
```

or using [twitch-dl](https://github.com/ihabunek/twitch-dl/)

which you could execute a command like

```
twitch-dl download twitchVideoURL
```

Way 2
use purely [twitch-dl](https://github.com/ihabunek/twitch-dl/)

This way you would end up running
`twitch-dl videos twitchChannelName`
which would give you an output as follows (this just grabbed off his github readme)

```
Found 33 videos

221837124
SUPER MARIO ODYSSSEY - Stream #2 / 600,000,000
Bananasaurus_Rex playing Super Mario Odyssey
Published 2018-01-24 @ 12:05:25  Length: 3h 40min

221418913
Dead Space and then SUPER MARIO ODYSSEY PogChamp
Bananasaurus_Rex playing Dead Space
Published 2018-01-23 @ 02:40:58  Length: 6h 2min
```

From there you could grab the first line of each new video. Finally putting that id into
`twitch-dl download VideoID`

Hopefully this gives you some ideas as to how to do this. As you never specified a language I tried to for the most part be as generic as possible.